# hbase configurations multiple environments

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have two different configurations and I just wanted to keep the codebase the same in my repositories. Is it better to keep different branches in git... or is it POSSIBLE to have different hbase/hadoop configs based on naming conventions in the file and ENV variables or "active profile".

e.g.

Active-profile: PRODUCTION_HEROKU

vs

Active profile: PRODUCTION_AWS

and have something like

hbase-production-aws.xml + hbase-production-heroku.xml (both files in classpath) instead of hbase-site.xml ?

Point is, I have configuration files like this:

hbase-site.xml
core-site.xml
hdfs-site.xml

Can I rename them and have apache hadoop/hbase auto-detect them based on some variable or active-profile?